# where's implementation of OracleCommand class's methods?

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm working on a web-based application involved database. When I'm reading the existing code, I find no implementation for OracleCommand class.

I checked the class file, every method body is empty. And I don't think OracleCommand class is inherited in my project. Also the methods are not abstract. For example, they are like this:

```
public override int ExecuteNonQuery();
public OracleDataReader ExecuteReader();
```

I wonder how does it work *(It works)*? I mean where's the sql command. And how does it works with database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.Data.OracleCient`

[image: add namespace System.Data.OracleCient]

Comment: Then you can use something like reflector or IL Spy (free) to decompile the code in the assembly.